# Use bottomsheet's action to open another dialogfragment without crashing android navigation component

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-architecture-components, bottom-sheet, android-architecture-navigation

I have Fragment A, BottomSheetDialogFragment B, and DialogFragment C. I want to be able to choose an action from B, dismiss B to go back to A, then use the navigation livedata to navigate from A to C.

A and B shares the same activityViewModel. My intention is that when the action button in B is clicked, it will dismiss B, modify a flag in the activityViewModel, and A will observe change to the flag and open C subsequently. However, I get an error and I think that it think I'm navigating from B to C (instead of A to C):

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination ...action_FragmentA_to_DialogFragmentC is unknown to this NavController

I believe the exception is due to program thinks the action is instead from B to C.

```
class DetailBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    private val detailViewModel by activityViewModels<DetailViewModel>() { viewModelFactory }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding.bottomSheetAction.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
            detailViewModel.setBottomSheetDialogType(1)
        }
    }
}

class DetailFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    private val detailViewModel by activityViewModels<DetailViewModel>() { viewModelFactory }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        detailViewModel.bottomSheetDialogType.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            when (it) {
                1 -> detailViewModel.navigateToDialogFragmentC(args.id)
                else -> {}
            }
        })

        detailViewModel.navigateToDialogFragmentC.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            WrapperEventObserver {
                Thread.sleep(500) // thought this would allow wait time for bottomsheet to dismiss, but doesn't make a difference
                val action =
                    DetailFragmentDirections.actionFragmentAToDialogFragmentC(it)
                findNavController().navigate(action)
            })
    }
}
```

What fixes are available to me navigate properly in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `dismiss()` on any `DialogFragment` asynchronously updates the `NavController` state - this means that from `NavController`'s perspective, you **are** still on `DetailBottomSheet` when your `bottomSheetDialogType` Observer fires.

You should instead use `findNavController().popBackStack()`, which will synchronously update the `NavController`'s state (effectively moving you back to A) and calling `dismiss()` itself to hide the bottom sheet dialog.

```
binding.bottomSheetAction.setOnClickListener {
    findNavController().popBackStack()
    detailViewModel.setBottomSheetDialogType(1)
}
```